# Profile Sychronization Instance list does not list all WFE servers on farm to choose from

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, sharepoint-on-prem, failover

[image]I want to create a UPA on a second WFE that serves as a failover WFE server, however the list of "Select the machine in this farm on which you would like to run Profile Synchronization process." only has the first WFE listed .. How can I add a new UPA for the second server to be able to run it when the first server is down?

[image]

Comment: which SharePoint version you are using?

Comment: 2013 on premise

Comment: are you using the MIM or ADI or anything else?

Comment: how can i check please?

Comment: Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service and everything is installed and running.. - i added an image, that list only lists the first front end sevrer,  but not the actual one where i want to create upa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only run one instance of the User Profile Synchronization service on a farm. it is kind of limitation. You cant have multiple instances of UPA sync.

But you can start User profile Service instance on multiple servers in farm.

[Plan for the synchronization server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/plan-profile-synchronization-for-sharepoint-server-2013#plan-for-the-synchronization-server)

Try to run the below script against each server, replace Servername with ur each time. (this will list the UPA service instance on each server)

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
$TypeName = "User Profile Synchronization Service"
$ServerName = "SERVERNAME" #Replace with your server name where the service is stuck on Starting

Get-SPServiceInstance | where-object {$_.TypeName -eq $TypeName -and $_.Server.Address -eq $ServerName}
```

Comment: You can only run one instance of the User Profile Synchronization service on a farm. The computer on which the User Profile Synchronization service runs is called the synchronization server. <-- and what if the sync server is down?

Comment: You have to manually start the sync service on the 2nd server.

Comment: Ok so I do not know if this is the root issue of my problem at this  point. I have 2013 Designer Workflows running, but when the 1st WFE server, where UPA is hosted, is down, I get authorization errors on the workflow: An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException_Logging :: UserProfileApplicationProxy.ApplicationProperties ProfilePropertyCache does not have Claims Authentication

Isnt that because of USer Profile Sync?

Comment: I also have these event logs when I run sync on the second server: The management agent "MOSS-UserProfile" failed on run profile "MOSS_EXPORT_GUID" because the server encountered errors.

Comment: there are two thing, user profile service and user profile sync service....could you please check if User profile Service (bottom on the page, Service on Server page from central admin) is running on both WFE, i think your problem with UPA instance not UPA sync.

Comment: I do not have it listed (see new image above). It is only listed on first WFE. Only Sync is appearing on both servers..

Comment: i think, User profile service should be on all server in the farm, i am not sure, could you please run the script to check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90038/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mvp-and-saz-mifsud).